# Passing quotes to nCover.console?

Tags: c#, ncover

I'm calling ncover.console.exe and passing in parameters to be passed onto another program.  One of those parameters has spaces in it, so I put it in quotes.

However - ncover then strips off the quotes before passing the parameters on!

Anyone else had this problem?  And solved it?

Thanks!

Comment: more details please. call it from where? command line? NAnt? MSBuild? could you post the command.

Answer (score 0):

What version of NCover are you using?

NCover v2.1.2+ should handle this.

Thank you
Joe Feser
NCover